# Updating DLL of a C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a project that uses a DLL that I have created. Everything works wonderfully, but I am now extending the library in the DLL to optimize some older functions.

What I was wondering is if I just modify the library to where only the main function body changes and nothing else can I just rebuild the DLL and replace it with the old one or is it because the function body changed I need to rebuild any projects that used this DLL.

The main reason I asked is because all of these projects have me referencing the .lib file and to be honest I am not sure what is exactly in a .lib file of a DLL project.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just changing the functions to optimize them, without changing the function signatures, then you can just build your library and deploy it (replacing the old library).

However, if you need to change the function signatures then you can do one of (at least) two things:

1. Modify the code that's using your library to use the new function signatures.
2. If #1 is not an option, then consider leaving the old function and deprecating it. Applications with make use of your latest version will have to avoid using the deprecated methods.

You can read more about .lib/.dll here: http://www.screenio.com/tips/dll.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you only change function bodies, and those functions are not template functions, and you compile the dll with the same compile options, as you did back then, you should be fine.

You might have to take care that both the dll and your executable use the same version of the Microsoft C++ Runtime Library. The version of it, that will be loaded, can be overriden by manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

The .lib file lets you write code that uses your DLL as though it was a static library. Essentially it contains the declarations of all the functions in your DLL. It is generated whenever you build the DLL, but if you don't add (or remove, but you should never remove once you've deployed) a function, or change the signature of a function, then it won't change. You will also have a header file to tell the compiler what functions are in your DLL and this you will change by hand when you add a function or change the signature of a function.

If your only change is a bugfix (or perf improvement or whatever) to the actual code inside a function, you can get away with deploying only the updated DLL. For other changes you must deploy the lib and the DLL. If you've changed the signature of a function you'll have to deploy the new .h, change the calling code to call with the revised parameters, and then get the calling code recompiled. If you just added something you can get away with not rebuilding the calling code.